# Properties preserved by categorical quotient (after Mumford's GIT)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, geometric-invariant-theory

*A categorical quotient* of a variety $X$ acted by $G$ is a morphism $f: X \to Y$ constant on $G$-orbits such that every $h: X \to Z$ constant on $G$-orbits factors through it.

Mumford on the page 5 of *Geometric Invariant Theory* states that if $X$ is

1. reduced,
2. connected,
3. irreducible,
4. locally integral,
5. or locally integral and normal,

then $Y=X//G$ also is. Is it really obvious from the universal property (and why)?

Answer (score 2):

First, let me make your statement a bit more precise. Saying the map factors through it (in your first line), while correct, should be there exists a unique morphism $g:Y\to Z$ etc.

Now, let me do this for 1. If $Y$ is not reduced, then let $Z=Y_{red}$. So, Then it is clear that $f$ factors through $Z$ and then you have $h:X\to Z$ and thus $g:Y\to Z$. Now, we have two maps $Id:Y\to Y, g:Y\to Z\subset Y$, and so by uniqueness, $Id=g$ as morphisms and then easy to see that $Y=Z$.

Comment: Do you know what "locally integral" means? This question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146415/what-is-locally-integral-in-mumfords-git-book?noredirect=1&lq=1 never got answered.

Comment: @Bananeen $X$ is Locally integral means $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is an integral domain for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I guess Vakil just bakes that into the definition of normality in his notes.

Comment: 1. seems easier than e.g. 3 or 4.  How do you see those from universal properties?

Comment: @Mohan I too don't see how the irreducibility of $Y$ follows directly from the irreducibility of $X$ via the approach you've outlined. Would be grateful if you could provide some more details.

Comment: @user940160 The image of $X$ has the required ub

Comment: @user940160 The closure of the image of $X$ has the required universal property.

Comment: @Mohan Indeed, yes I have a managed to prove that the scheme theoretic image of $X$ satisfies the universal property of the quotient, but is it in general true that scheme theoretic images of irreducible schemes are irreducible too? 
(Note: I only just noticed that the OP has said that we're working with varieties, but is this statement true more generally for arbitrary schemes too?)