# What is "locally integral" in Mumford's GIT book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

I think "locally integral" means for each point of a scheme, its local ring is a domain. In my definition, "normal" obviously implies "locally integral". But "normal" and "locally integral" is mentioned independently in Mumford's GIT book, as the image below.
[image]

What is definition of "locally integral"? And if my definition of it is correct, how can I prove that "locally integral" is preserved by taking a categorical quotient?

Comment: [EGA I](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1960__4__5_0), 2.1.8, says that a locally integral prescheme is one for which every point has a neighbourhood that is reduced and irreducible.